# File write error- Incomplete file

Tags: python, file-io

I have a large file on which i have implemented a graph algorithm. There is no problem with program. However i have to write the output into a file. My input will be a number and the output will be the all the nodes the input node is connected to. The file generated is fairly large and after about 4-5 pages stops abruptly. I came across and used the `flush()` function but to no avail.

My file write code is:

```
djkpath =(path[i]," -> ",path[i+1], "[weight = ", g.weights[(path[i], path[i+1])],"]")
            #print(path[i] -> path[i+1] [weight = g.weights[(path[i], path[i+1])]])
            finaldjk = " ".join(map(str, djkpath))
            fo.write(finaldjk)
            fo.write('\n')

fo.write('\n')
fo.write("}")
fo.close()
fo.flush()
```

The file generated looks like(i have just included the end of the file that looks incomplete):

```
150  ->  75 [weight =  12 ]
75  ->  45 [weight =  25 ]
85  ->  150 [weight =  9 ]
150  ->  55 [weight =  7 ]
55  ->  20 [weight =  17 ]
20  ->  120 [weight =  7 ]
120  ->  43 [weight
```

Comment: Flushing a closed file can't do anything, and closing implies a flush anyway. I don't know whether this is your problem (it would be kind of weird if it is, in fact) but try removing your `fo.flush()`.

Comment: How do you open your file for writing? Also, have you considered using something like pickle or cPickle? Maybe pickle or cPickle don't meet your output format specifications, but they are very helpful otherwise.

Comment: I tried after removing the `fo.flush()`. Same problem @kindall

Comment: @urinieto- I have never used pickle and have no idea how to use it

Comment: @begin.py: pickle is really simple... just read the docs. The functions you will likely be mos interested in are `dump` and `load`

Comment: @Sheena- tried it,same problem- incomlete file and moreover getting a S' in each line